How do I add legend handles in Matplotlib?
I would like to add a legend to my Python plot, with a title and legend handles. My sincere apologies as a complete novice in Python, I got my code from a post. The code below works, but I want to add a legend. All the plots I have googled deal with line plots with several lines.
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map_df = gpd.read_file("../Shapefiles/lso_adm_fao_mlgca_2019/lso_admbnda_adm1_FAO_MLGCA_2019.shx")
risks_df=pd.read_csv("../Output/Wndrisks.csv")

merged_df = map_df.merge(risks_df, left_on=["ADM1_EN"], right_on=["District"])
d = {1: "green", 2: "yellow", 3: "orange", 4: "red"}
colors = map_df["ADM1_EN"].map(risks_df.set_index("District")["risk"].map(d))
ax = map_df.plot(color=colors, edgecolor="k", alpha=0.7, legend=True, legend_kwds={"label": "Risk Level", "orientation": "vertical"})

map = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlon=26.5,llcrnrlat=-31.0,urcrnrlon=30.0,urcrnrlat=-28.5, epsg=4269)
map.drawlsmask(land_color='grey',ocean_color='aqua',lakes=True)

legend = plt.legend(handles=[one, two, three, four], title="Risk Levels",
                loc=4, fontsize='small', fancybox=True)

plt.title(f"Strong Wind Risks 01-10Jun24", y=1.04)

plt.tick_params(
axis="both",        # affect both the X and Y
which="both",       # get rid of both major and minor ticks
top=False,          # get rid of ticks top/bottom/left/right
bottom=False,
left=False,
right=False,
labeltop=False,     # get rid of labels top/bottom/left/right
labelbottom=False,
labelleft=False,
labelright=False)

plt.axis("off")          # Get rid of the border around the map
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85) # Nudge the country to the left a bit

plt.savefig('wndriskmap.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()

The data is for the form:
"District","risk"
"Berea",3
"Butha-Buthe",4
"Leribe",4
"Mafeteng",4
"Maseru",4
"Mohale's Hoek",4
"Mokhotlong",4
"Qacha's Nek",4
"Quthing",4
"Thaba-Tseka",4

The plot I get is as attached
I can attach the shapefile if required. I want the legend to have a title "Risk Level" and the levels 1=no risk, 2=low risk, 3=medium risk and 4=high risk. what I have included in legend = plt.legend(...) does not work.
Assistance will be appreciated.

You could map the risks to the labels and make a categorical plot :
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

colors = {1: "green", 2: "yellow", 3: "orange", 4: "red"}  # or a list
labels = {1: "no risk", 2: "low risk", 3: "medium risk", 4: "high risk"}
catego = map_df["risk"].astype(str).str.cat(map_df["risk"].map(labels), sep="- ")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

map_df.plot(
    column=catego,
    categorical=True,
    edgecolor="k",
    alpha=0.7,
    cmap=ListedColormap(colors.values()),
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={
        "title": "Risk Level",
        "shadow": True,
        "loc": "lower right",
    },
    ax=ax,
)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_title("Strong Winds in 10-D Risks 01-10Jun")

NB: I used the risks as a prefix/workaround to preserve the labels' order in the legend.


Thank you infinitely @Timeless. This is exactly what I am looking for. However, i am not able to make the code work, I am not sure which lines to remove from my original code. I have been doing trial and error and am always getting error. I will appreciate further guidance.

You're welcome. Which errors are you getting ? Your full code should look like this.

The code you have given works perfectly. Once again thanks very much

Hello @Timeless, i hope i can still reach you. I really like the resulting graphic from the script but I have a problem to which I am not sure if there is a solution. If I have 3 risk levels, 1, 2, 3 they are supposed to be green, yellow and orange, but I i green yellow and red. Similarly if I have only level 4 I want red, but I get green with legend as high risk. Is there a way of forcing the colors. I will appreciate your guidance.

Hi @ZiloreMumba, you can replace cmap=ListedColormap(colors.values()) with cmap=ListedColormap([c for r,c in colors.items() if r in map_df["risk"].unique()]). For the example you share, you should get this.

Thanks so much @Timeless, it works perfectly. I really appreciate.

I need further help moving the legend. I have tried adding "loc": "lower right", "bbox_to_anchor": "(1.05, .5)", using guidance in "legend.py", line 1132" where it says if l == 2:
bbox = [bbox[0], bbox[1], 0, 0] somehow am not able to interpret the code here correctly

Please excuse me everybody who has looked at this. I made an error quoting the coordinates part of the string "bbox_to_anchor": "(1.05, .5)". Put as "bbox_to_anchor": (1.05, .5), it works without error.

Hello @timeless, I hope i can still reach. My problem is not really about coding. You assisted me a lot to get my graphic, combining a shapefile and a csv. It is working very well. I extended the same python code to graph at adm2 level. I am really baffled that the polygons that get colored are way to the left of the actual position. I am not able to post an example since this is just comment. I am not sure if this has to do with the code. I tohught before I posted a new question, if you have time, you may be able to advise.
